# Fedora Core 13 and VSFTPD issues

Tags: iptables, fedora, ftp

I am running Fedora Core 13 and I have vsftpd (vsftpd-2.2.2-7.fc13.x86_64) up and running, and I can login, but it keeps hanging:

```
$ ftp xxx.local
Connected to xxx.local.
220 (vsFTPd 2.2.2)
Name (xxx.local:xxx): xxx
331 Please specify the password.
Password: 
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
```

It hangs for a while, then returns...

```
421 Service not available, remote server timed out. Connection closed.
```

Here is my vsftpd.conf:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
xferlog_std_format=NO
listen=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_deny=NO
tcp_wrappers=YES
```

Here is my IPTABLES:

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5150 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

I also have the following added to my iptables-config:

```
IPTABLES_MODULES="nf_conntrack_ftp"
```

Any ideas as to why it is hanging at that point?

Answer (score 0):

Try using lftp to get a better debugging set of output as a client and paste it here; for instance:

```
$ lftp -u <username> localhost
Password: 
lftp user@localhost:~> debug 5  
lftp user@localhost:~> ls
---- Connecting to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 21
<--- 220 (vsFTPd 2.2.2)          
---> FEAT
<--- 211-Features:
<---  EPRT
<---  EPSV
<---  MDTM
<---  PASV
<---  REST STREAM
<---  SIZE
<---  TVFS
<---  UTF8
<--- 211 End
---> OPTS UTF8 ON
<--- 200 Always in UTF8 mode.
---> USER user
<--- 331 Please specify the password.
---> PASS XXXX
<--- 230 Login successful.       
---> PWD
<--- 257 "/home/user"
---> PASV
<--- 227 Entering Passive Mode (127,0,0,1,159,49).
---- Connecting data socket to (127.0.0.1) port 40753
---> LIST
<--- 150 Here comes the directory listing.
<--- 226 Directory send OK.
```

We need to see better client side debugging to figure out where the connection is hanging; most likely it's passive ports. I don't trust the iptables module, instead in the vsftpd.conf set the min and max ports:

```
ftp_data_port=20
listen_port=21
pasv_min_port=64123
pasv_max_port=64321
```

...then open that range in your iptables. I prefer to be explicit rather than implicit when dealing with ports.